# Divisible Problem on Hackerearth Partially Accepted

Tags: c

I completed a challenge in HackerEarth using C but the solution is only partially accepted. I tried to change the data type also but no success.

Question is:

> You are given an array A of size N that contains integers. Here, N is an even number. You are required to perform the following operations:
>
> - Divide the array of numbers in two equal halves
>   Note: Here, two equal parts of a test case are created by dividing the array into two equal parts.
> - Take the first digit of the numbers that are available in the first half of the array (first 50% of the test case)
> - Take the last digit of the numbers that are available in the second half of the array (second 50% of the test case)
> - Generate a number by using the digits that have been selected in the above steps
>
> Your task is to determine whether the newly-generated number is divisible by 11.

My solution is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int A[N];

    for(int i = 0;i < N;i++)
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
    
    long int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < N/2;i++){
        int digits =(int)log10(A[i]);
        int first_digit = (int)(A[i] / pow(10,digits));
        sum = (sum*10) + first_digit;
    }

    for(int i = N/2;i < N;i++){
        int last_digit = A[i] % 10;
        sum = (sum*10)+last_digit;
    }

    sum % 11 == 0? printf("OUI"):printf("NON");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using floating point functions `log10` and `pow`, while you should limit yourself to integer calculations. Getting digits of a number is easily achievable using only int calculations.

Comment: Note that on a system where `long` is 32-bits, your code can only work for N = 2, 4, 6, or 8. For larger values of N, `sum` will overflow.

Answer (score 1):

[The problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/ja/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/divisibe-or-2d8e196a/) says that `N` will be upto 100,000.

Dealing with such many digits, the calculation of `sum` will cause overflow.

You should divide `sum` by 11 and take modulo after each update of `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use floating-point numbers or built-in integer types for this kind of problems, because their precisions wouldn't be enough. An integer number is divisible by 11 if the alternating sum of its decimal digits is divisible by 11. So a simple solution would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    int sum = 0, sign = 1;
    int n, i;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        char num[100];
        scanf("%s", num);
        sum += sign * (num[i < n / 2 ? 0 : strlen(num) - 1] - '0');
        sign = -sign;
    }

    puts(sum % 11 == 0 ? "OUI" : "NON");
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Error checking and input validation is omitted for brevity.

Comment: Please can you explain the logic behind this?

Answer (score 0):

100 pecent accepted hackerearth Divisible problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  long int N;
  scanf("%ld", &N);
  long int a[N];
  int m = 0, n = 0, i;

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    scanf("%ld", &a[i]);

  for (i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {
    if (a[i] >= 100000)
      a[i] = a[i] / 100000;
    else if (a[i] >= 10000)
      a[i] = a[i] / 10000;
    else if (a[i] >= 1000)
      a[i] = a[i] / 1000;
    else if (a[i] >= 100)
      a[i] = a[i] / 100;
    else if (a[i] >= 10)
      a[i] = a[i] / 10;
    else
      a[i] = a[i];
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      m += a[i];
    else
      n += a[i];
  }

  for (i = N / 2; i < N; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      m += (a[i] % 10);
    else
      n += (a[i] % 10);
  }

  if ((abs(m - n)) == 0 || ((abs(m - n)) % 11) == 0)
    printf("OUI");
  else
    printf("NON");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function divisibilty(n, arr) {
  return arr[n - 1] % 10 == 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
}

console.log(divisibilty(5, [185, 125, 165, 211, 814])); // No
console.log(divisibilty(2, [98, 70])); // Yes
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).